# How to convert an iOS NSLocale localeIdentifier to a Java Locale?

Tags: java, ios

I have the string value produced by [`NSLocale localeIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLocale/localeIdentifier), and I need to construct a [`java.util.Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). I have [`org.apache.commons.lang3.LocaleUtils#toLocale`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/LocaleUtils.html#toLocale(java.lang.String)) for parsing Java locales, but this isn't working for all cases. For example, values such as `en_TH@calendar=gregorian` and `zh-Hans_TH` result in `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: I had the same problem. Ended up checking for the @ character and cut the string after it. It works - but as I was not aware of the `zh-Hans_TH` issue i suspect there are more special cases... so I'm curious myself if someone comes up with a better solution. :-)

Comment: I'm doing something similar to deal with the @: `split("@")(0)`. Talk about hacky, and insufficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `org.apache.commons.lang3.LocaleUtils#toLocale` does not support all the features the iOS locale. Apple has [documentation describing the language and locale ID format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html). The locale can be one of these formats:

- `[language designator]`
- `[language designator]_[region designator]`
- `[language designator]-[script designator]`
- `[language designator]-[script designator]_[region designator]`

Where `[language designator]` is ISO 639, `[region designator]` is ISO 3166, and `[script designator]` is ISO 15924. This documentation does not define `@`, but I don't think we need it for a `java.util.Locale`.

Here is a `java.util.regex.Pattern` for matching iOS locale:

```
public static final Pattern localePattern = Pattern.compile(
    "^(?<lang>\\p{Lower}{2,3})" + // always match lang
    "(-(?<script>\\p{Upper}\\p{Lower}{3}))?" + // optional script
    "(_(?<region>(\\p{Upper}{2}|\\p{Digit}{3})))?" + // optional region
    "(_(?<variant>\\p{Alnum}+))?" + // optional variant
    "(@.+)?$" // optional @ stuff
);
```

Here is a method that builds `java.util.Locale` from an iOS locale.

```
public static Locale parse(String locale) {
    final Matcher m = localePattern.matcher(locale);
    if (m.find()) {
        return new Locale.Builder()
                .setLanguage(m.group("lang"))
                .setScript(m.group("script"))
                .setRegion(m.group("region"))
                .setVariant(m.group("variant"))
                .build();
    } else throw new IllegalArgumentException(locale);
}
```